# Handling Languages in D&D, or is the Linguist Feat desirable?

Tags: dnd-4e, languages

The Linguist feat gives three extra languages. A feat for 3 languages seems problematic and not balanced with all the other feats available, many of which seem highly desirable and the feat doesn't seemed balanced in desirability with others given the combat nature of most feats.

How can I balance a desire for languages and complexity in culture in D&D against this feat? Is this a mechanics, a setting or a story style solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As written, the Linguist feat seems to be a poor choice for most players in most campaigns.

If languages are useful in your campaign, then the feat will be desirable. Making languages useful is difficult. If you make language use essential, then you run the risk of frustrating players when they cannot communicate with NPCs. "Hand signal" role-play is only fun the first time.

**Don't make languages annoying**

You want to emphasis complexity in culture, but you don't want to annoy players.

Hand-wave the common spoken languages. Just let characters talk to each other. Which languages are common depends on your setting. Probably the major races all speak a smattering of each other's languages. Another way to think of this: the old "Common" language is really a mash-up of useful human, elven, and dwarven words and grammar.

**A little carrot: Make knowing languages useful**

Emphasize the importance of being able to read exotic languages like Draconian and Infernal. Ancient books full of writing in these languages contain long forgotten secrets!

If a character "knows" a language, explain linguistic quirks to the player. For example, don't just tell them that the elf is angry; explain that the idiom the elf is using goes something like "I wouldn't waste a second on you," and because elves live hundreds of years, this is much more meaningful than if a human said it.

To give the Linguist feat a bit more bite, house rule it so that the player also gets a +1 linguist bonus to Diplomacy checks when speaking to a person in their native tongue and a +1 linguist bonus to History checks when recalling information about that culture. The bonuses apply to all languages that the character knows, not just the three new ones.

**A little stick: Make not knowing languages inconvenient**

Maybe characters know enough language to have a basic conversation, but their lack of true understanding hurts them when nuance of dialect is important. A character who makes a skill check that relies upon verbal communication, but who does not know the language, takes a -5 -5 penalty on those skill checks. Maybe even on checks involving nonverbal communication, since so much depends on culture.

Answer (score 17):

The feat has great utility... if you are not running 4E in a boardgame mode.

In non-combat encounters, most of the action should be taking place in a single area, and the PC's should speak the primary language. They also should be speak their ethnic tongues.

If you want to make it both more realistic in play and more useful, have most people in towns speaking their ethnic tongues. They speak common to the outsiders... but not to each other.

Likewise, in combat, one can not understand the opponent's chatter and taunts unless you know their language. Many bard powers could be nerfed... and not a few others, as well.

It's an area that can safely be ignored, but opting to not ignore it makes the feat quite useful.

Comment: Upvoted for the insight into bard-and-other-linguistic powers.

Comment: This is why, when going up against a certain DM, I make sure we have a party member that speaks Goblin.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that for bluff/intimidate/disguise checks, language is incredibly helpful. I had a character (shapeshifter) who didn't have many language skills, so his disguises weren't nearly as effective.

Another character does have a lot of language skills, so everyone goes to her when there are clues in a foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

Languages can be vital to how your team communicates both with other people and themselves. By knowing multiple languages, a player can have a better chance of getting information out of NPC, both by making conversation easier for those who don't speak common as well as others and by understanding what certain NPC are taking about when eavesdropping in on a conversation.

Languages are also useful for communicating with a team when you don't want to be understood by anyone else, such as communicating to a dwarf about treasure while you're in a room full of goblins and thieves.

Overall, the linguist feat is useful to those who are leading others or running the diplomatic side of your party. However, there is very little use for this feat if you are in no way capable of succeeding a charisma check, so don't choose it unless you are useful in conversation scenarios.